# Sql trigger for update in specific column after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I made a trigger that is supposed to update another value in the same table a after I make an insert to the table. I do get the result I am looking for, but when I ask my teacher if it is correct he responded that this trigger updates "all" tables(?) and thus incorrect. He would not explain more than that (he is that kind of teacher...). Can anyone understand what he means? Not looking for the right code, just an explanation of what I might have misunderstood.

```
CREATE TRIGGER setDate
ON Loans
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Loans
set date = GETDATE()
END;
```

Comment: Your trigger will update ALL rows in table `Loans`. Not just in the inserted rows. That is because you do not have a `where` clause in your code. Use the `inserted` table that is already known in the trigger for this `where`clause

Comment: @GuidoG I see! One idea I have is:
    
    UPDATE Loans
    SET date = GETDATE() + 14
    WHERE (SELECT date_due FROM INSERTED) = null

(Only news is what comes after "WHERE") Since I have a not null constraint on this column this should limit the UPDATE to the row in question, right?

Comment: no that is not neccesary. You have an insert trigger which means all rows in inserted are only new rows. So more like `update loans set date = getdate() where LoanID in (select LoanID from inserted) `

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher intends to say that the query updates all *rows* in the table -- perhaps you misunderstood her or him.

The best way to do what you want is to use a default value:

```
alter table loans alter column date datetime default getdate();
```

That is, a trigger is not needed.  If you did use a trigger, I'll give you two hints:

- An `instead of` trigger.
- `inserted` should be somewhere in the trigger.

Comment: And I will suggest that an instead-of trigger is far more complicated than a regular after trigger - especially in this case and with OP's level of knowledge. And since the goal of this exercise seems to be learning triggers, let's not cause more confusion than necessary.

Comment: @SMor . . . There is a correct way to do what the OP is asking and it does not involve a trigger.  This is not a "homework-helper" site.  This is a site to answer questions about technical coding issues (in this case regarding SQL and databases).

Answer (score 0):

*Hello there. I upvoted your question because that might be the question of many beginners in SQL Server*.

As I see you defined the trigger right! It is a correct way although it's **not the best**.
By the way we are not discussing all ways you could choose or not, I'm gonna correct your code and explain what your teacher meant.

Look at this UPDATE you wrote:

```
UPDATE Loans
SET date = GETDATE()
```

If you write a SELECT without a WHERE clause, what does it do? It would result **all the rows** in the table which was selected. right?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.loans
```

So without a WHERE clause, your UPDATE will **update all of the rows in the table**.

---

OK now what to do to just update the only row ( or rows) which were recently inserted?
When you are writing a trigger, you are allowed to use this table: `Inserted`
which it has the rows were recently inserted. kinda these rows first come to this table and then go to the final destination table. **So you can update them before they go the `dbo.loans`**
it would be like this:

```
Update dbo.loans
SET date = GETDATE()
WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM Inserted)
```